# Panic - Coda. Code navigator doesn't recognize PHP

Tags: php, coda

So, its simply began to be too lazy to parse my php code and it doesn't show anything. Only comments. No functions, no classes. How can i fix it?

```
   Syntax-mode is correct: PHP-HTML.
```

Comment: So Coda isn't using it's autocomplete function?

Comment: Hint: if you're in a bind, skip the 'funny style' and ask what you have on your mind. Chances are people are willing to look into it even if it is not that common of a question. So skip the personality show and get the question _clearly_ across

Comment: What is not clear exactly in my question ? A bit of fun is really important for our everyday life. My problem is that Code navigator (do you know whats this?) is not showing my PHP functions, only TODO: marks. I didnt even ask about autocomplete or hints, btw.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a coding question per-se... But Coda doesn't have any autocompletion that actually reads you code, it just shows functions from the manual .

Comment: Did you read the title of my question? Was it so hard to understand?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the "hint" option is enabled (on the bottom of the view)

[image]

More tips and tricks (30) can be found [here](http://www.upstartblogger.com/30-panic-coda-tips-and-tricks).